# ng-transclude does not work any more after JQuery update

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

This is a weird issue i have started to encounter after the latest JQuery update.

We use angularjs `1.7.9` in out app. We have following component. It is basically a date field wrapper .

```
export class DateFieldComponent {
  ...
  transclude: any = {
    iconContent: "?iconContent",
  };
  template: string = `
    <div>
      <span
        ng-click="$ctrl.focusInput()"
        ng-transclude="iconContent"
      />
      <input
        ...
      ></input>
    </div>
  `;
}

angular.module("App").component("dateField", new DateFieldComponent());
```

As you can see, we use ng-transclude to load an icon on to the input field. We made it in this way so that whoever using this component can dynamically add the icon from the client side.

This component was working fine until we updated `JQuery` from `3.4.0` to `3.5.0` . After the update the `dateField` has issues. However there are no console errors. But i was able to pin point the issue to below line

```
ng-transclude="iconContent"
```

So if i remove this line, everything works fine. Adding this line back makes the component to not to render properly.

I know for a fact that JQuery update has no effect on angularjs cause angularjs uses its own `jquery-lite` version. Also as far as i know, `ng-transclude` has nothing to do with `JQuery`.

Also i noticed that there are similar issues in all the places we use ng-transclude in our app, after this update.

What am i missing here ? Any clue would be much appreciated.

Comment: AngularJS only uses its jq-lite if it is loaded before jQuery. Otherwise it uses whatever jQuery that is available globally on the page. On an unrelated note, writing `transclude: any = {
    iconContent: "?iconContent",
  };` is pretty awful; write `transclude = {
    iconContent: "?iconContent",
  };` or just stop using TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we made a simple mistake in the markup which is not working anymore with JQuery 3.5.0 version

this was the culprit

```
<span
  ng-click="$ctrl.focusInput()"
  ng-transclude="iconContent"
/>
```

fix was to close the `span` properly like below

```
<span
  ng-click="$ctrl.focusInput()"
  ng-transclude="iconContent">
<span/>
```